# TypeScript not finding declaration file

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use `nodemailer-express-handlebars` but it does not have declaration files (i.e. `@types/nodemailer-express-handlebars`). If I run my application with `ts-node-dev`, I get this error (since I got `"noImplicitAny": true` in my `tsconfig.json`):

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'nodemailer-express-handlebars'. '[...]/node_modules/nodemailer-express-handlebars/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/nodemailer-express-handlebars` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'nodemailer-express-handlebars';`

4 import nodemailerExpressHandlebars from 'nodemailer-express-handlebars';
```

I tried creating the following `nodemailer-express-handlebars.d.ts` file inside `src/@types` as a workaround:

```js
declare module 'nodemailer-express-handlebars' {
  function nodemailerExpressHandlebars(data: any): any;

  module nodemailerExpressHandlebars {}
  export = nodemailerExpressHandlebars;
}
```

The error persists, even setting `"typeRoots": ["./src/@types", "./node_modules/@types"]` in `tsconfig.json`.